# Add an AWS VPC managed prefix list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I see in my VPC that I have several AWS Managed prefix lists.
For example, this one from dynamoDB and all the CIDR block from AWS, east-1 are managed by them

[image: c]

The CIDR are all managed by AWS. And I don't want to do it manually.
I know that whenever they update https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json, these CIDR are also updated.

[image]

I would like to add a new one, but this time for ec2, east-1

**com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ec2**

But I cant find any documentation tell how to add it from the UI.

Comment: Adding a bounty probably won’t help as there are no AWS managed prefix lists for EC2. You will have to create one yourself. See my answer and our discussion in the comments below.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a **custom prefix list** from the [prefix list dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=us-east-1#ManagedPrefixLists:) using the **Create prefix list** button. Alternatively, here is a deeplink (replace `region=us-east-1` with the region of your choice):

https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=us-east-1#CreatePrefixList:

However, according to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/managed-prefix-lists.html), you cannot create, modify, share, or delete an **AWS-managed prefix list**, and because Amazon S3 and DynamoDB are the only services accessible through a VPC Gateway Endpoint, there are no managed prefix lists for other services.

Comment: Hi Dennis, I have updated my question. I don't want to manually input the CIDR, I want AWS to automatically update them

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately that isn't possible at this time. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I mean I don't want to update/modify their aws* prefix list, I want to add another one, these were created automatically when I started using dynamodb and s3 (I got several from them). Now I want one more but for ec2..

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. Prefix lists are only needed for VPC Gateway Endpoints. Only S3 and DynamoDB use Gateway Endpoints. All other services use Interface Endpoints through respective ENIs. You don't need a prefix list for them.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to add one, I want my RDS to be available on all EC2, because the application server is a SaaS sitting on EC2, and I dont control that EC2

Comment: In that case you have to create your own. To my knowledge there are no AWS managed prefix lists for EC2.

Comment: Don't know if @DennisTraub answer is entirely accurate with regards to only S3/Dynamo having prefix lists. Here is a reference to other services that have manged prefix lists https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/working-with-aws-managed-prefix-lists.html. Additionally there interface VPC-endpoints use cases that may require routes via prefix lists, an example is where "central vpc-endpoint" where endpoints are created in Shared services account in a multi-account Organisation. PHZ associations may not work for all services supported by interface VPC-endpoint?!